Show that the circle $r=\sqrt{(1-\lambda/\beta)}$ is invariant under a given map $F$
With the given map
\begin{equation}
    F\begin{pmatrix}
        r\\
        \theta
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{cases}
        &\lambda r+\beta r^3\\
        &\theta+\frac{2\pi}{n}+\epsilon\sin{n\theta}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
show that  $r=\sqrt{(1-\lambda/\beta)}$ is invariant under $F$.
I am not sure how to solve this. Does one have to account for iterations $F^n(r,\theta)$ by the orbit period of $F$?
My take is the following:
Let us do the first iteration on the map $F$
\begin{equation}
    F\begin{pmatrix}
        r\\
        \theta
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{cases}
        &\lambda r+\beta r^3\\
        &\theta+\frac{2\pi}{n}+\epsilon\sin{n\theta}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    F^1\begin{pmatrix}
        r\\
        \theta
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{cases}
        &\lambda (\lambda r+\beta r^3)+\beta (\lambda r+\beta r^3)^3\\
        &(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{n}+\epsilon\sin{n\theta})+\frac{2\pi}{n}+\epsilon\sin{n(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{n}+\epsilon\sin{n\theta}) }
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then we insert for $\gamma= {r=\sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta}}$ in $r$ and obtain for $r$-dimension in $F^0$ and $F^1$, ignoring the $\theta$ dimension:
\begin{equation}
    F(\gamma)=\lambda ( \sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta})+\beta (\sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta})^3
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    F^1(\gamma)=\lambda ({\sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta}}+\beta (\sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta})^3)+\beta (\sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta})+\beta  (\sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta})^3)^3
\end{equation}
Put in for $\lambda=\beta=1$ and obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   &  F(\gamma)=1\cdot( 0)+1\cdot (0)^3=0\\
   & F^1(\gamma)=1\cdot (0+1\cdot(0)^3)+1\cdot(0)+1\cdot  (0)^3)^3=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
But I am not sure this is correct! Any comments appreciated
Thanks

Indeed, from your description there seems to be no reason to consider $\theta$, so the fixed point for $r$ is easily found.

Better just noting that
$$
\lambda \sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta}+\beta \left(\sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta}\right)^3=\sqrt{(1-\lambda)/\beta}.
$$
